# Finding the Mode of an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, mode

For the past few hours or so I've been trying to find the mode out of an `ArrayList`. In the program, you find the max, min, median, and mean as well. I've figured out all of those but I haven't been able to do the mode. I keep getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Here is my code so far:

```
public String getMode(){
  int mode = 0;
  int count = 0;

  for ( int i : file1 ){
    int x = file1.get(i);
    int tempCount = 1;

    for(int e : file1){
      int x2 = file1.get(e);

      if( x == x2)
        tempCount++;

      if( tempCount > count){
        count = tempCount;
        mode = x;
      }
    }
  }

  return ("The mode is " + mode);
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 181, Size: 108
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at FunNumber2.getMode(FunNumber2.java:75)
at FunNumber2Tester.main(FunNumber2Tester.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem

```
for ( int i : file1 ){
```

change it to

```
for ( int i = 0; i< file1.size() ; i++ ){
```

This syntax

```
for ( int i : file1 ){
```

is giving you the iterated value of file1, meaning that if `file1 = List([4,5,6])` then in the first iteration of the loop `i == 4 not 0`.

Obviously this would apply to the second loop as well.

Alternatively you could change

```
for ( int i : file1 ){
  int x = file1.get(i);
```

to

```
for ( int i : file1 ){
  int x = i;
```

And it would fix your problem.
Hope that helps.

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much, I knew it was a simple solution but I couldn't find it. Thanks again!